# .Net core and React uppy.io 110mb file upload exception "Unexpected end of request content."

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, nginx, react-typescript, uppy

I have a Asp.net core 3.1 api and react typescript application.

When large file uploaded then i get exception this error

"Unexpected end of request content."

[image]

React component is Uppy.io and upload method is XHR

I use nginx for request receive

I tried below solutions

1. nginx large file settings client_max_body_size 2000M;
2. Asp.net Core file settings options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = long.MaxValue;

But not work

I tried 20mb file to slowing down the browser for determine the problem. It is work.
In my opinion problem is not long upload time.

I tested on 110 mb file

Uppy.io component is progress 100 then waiting 30 second and throw exception

Comment: Is the app running in an environment with limited RAM? You might be getting an OOM error somewhere

Comment: @abdusco I checked server. It is vm and 7gb ram available. Application created with kestrel service not docker.

Comment: Are there any reverse proxies in front of nginx? A firewall perhaps? They might be dropping the connection once the request size exceeds a certain size. Check the browser console. Does anything strange happen when the upload stops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved to my problem.

I Added on below code on nginx location block.

It's Work

```
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
client_max_body_size 2000M;
proxy_request_buffering off;
proxy_send_timeout 1h;
proxy_read_timeout 1h;
```

Asp.net added to below code

```
services.Configure<FormOptions>(x =>
            {
                x.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
                x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue; 
            });
```